# Ajax call to get data from database

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I'm looking for a function to embed into an ASP page to call a MYSQL database and check for updates/changes every 60 seconds for example. Then post those updates to a table without the page refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#responsecontainer").load("getdata.asp");
      var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load("getdata.asp");
     }, 9000);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

"getdata.asp" contains the MYSQL query to check for updates